# No such file or directory, mf-runtime.h

Tags: c, compilation

I started getting a seg fault for a program I was working with so I decided to change to dcc in my makefile, which results in the error underneath. I'm going to be honest I'm not sure what it means, my working directory contains the following

```
ImageList.c  ImageList.o  QuadTree.c  QuadTree.o  img    img.o
ImageList.h  Makefile     QuadTree.h  images      img.c
```

So I struggle to see why I get the error "No such file or directory". I've snooped around for a solution and all I get is issues with mudflap. It's a long shot but any help is really really appreciated.

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

img : img.o QuadTree.o ImageList.o
        dcc -o img img.o QuadTree.o ImageList.o

img.o : img.c QuadTree.h ImageList.h
        dcc $(CFLAGS) -c img.c

QuadTree.o : QuadTree.c QuadTree.h
        dcc $(CFLAGS) -c QuadTree.c

ImageList.o : ImageList.c ImageList.h
        dcc $(CFLAGS) -c ImageList.c

clean :
        rm -f img img.o QuadTree.o ImageList.o core


dcc -Wall -g -c QuadTree.c
cc1: fatal error: mf-runtime.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [QuadTree.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What is `dcc` on your system? (What system is this even on?)

Comment: I used gcc for the compilation and it compiles, but I get a seg fault when I run it. So I've been told to replace gcc with dcc and "it will (hopefully) warn you when you have not allocated space correctly" could this error be caused simply because I'm using dcc instead. thanks

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that the default include paths for `gcc` and `dcc` are different.  Is the “missing” file in an external library?  Try locating it yourself on your disk and adding an appropriate `-I` flag to the compiler command line.

Comment: I'm running this through my unis ssh which doesn't allow me to do this. If it compiles with gcc, do you think I am better off just finding whatever is causing the seg fault myself?

Comment: Previously asked here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672359/fatal-error-mf-runtime-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: compile the program with GCC and the -gdb3 parameter, then you could run the program using GBD (a debugger) then when it seg faults, enter 'bt' to get a back trace to show what initiated the seg fault (most likely cause is a 'wild' pointer.